# Connect 1/2" supply line to 3/8" outer diameter faucet line

Tags: water, faucet, plumbing-fixture, connectors

I bought from Home Depot a [Glacier faucet](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Kiso-Single-Hole-1-Handle-Low-Arc-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Chrome-86CR211WFSOLFHD/203005037) that comes with 3/8 inch O.D. supply tubes. The supply lines from the wall have an outer diameter of 1/2 inches though. How do I connect the two?

[image]

This seems like a common enough question, but searching for "connector" I could only find [this connector](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Power-Care-Male-M22-x-3-8-in-Male-NPT-Connector-for-Pressure-Washer-AP31035A/100664026) on Home Depot's site, which is from 3/8" to "M22". I'm not sure why "M22" is called that way, but [its diameter is apparently 14mm](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Power-Care-Male-M22-x-Male-M22-14-mm-4500-PSI-Pressure-Washer-Hose-to-Hose-Coupler-AP31087/203353080), which isn't exactly 1/2".

[Brass nipples](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-1-2-in-Lead-Free-Brass-Hex-Nipple-LF-A833/202254955) on Home Depot's site seem to come only in the same diameter on both ends, e.g. 1/2".

<sup>(As you might suspect, I'm originally from Europe and have quite a bit of disdain for the imperial system and the US hanging on to it when the entire rest of the world uses metric.)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You need a brass connector. "1/2" female iron pipe" (1/2" FIP) is the size of the female connector on the end of the hose coming out of the sink plate in your picture; "3/8" female compression" is the size of the connector on the end of the hose coming out of the faucet in your picture. You need a 1/2" MIP (male iron pipe) X 3/8" male compression adapter. Super common at any hardware store, er... should I say "ironmonger shop"? 
[image]

Comment: "Iron Pipe" sizes are also called National Pipe Taper (NPT), and male / female may be labeled MPT or FPT, respectively.

Comment: @Henry Jackson, thanks I should have thought to mention that. Very common to see the same size referenced with NPT. Also I should have noted that the picture shows the fitting with a compression nut and ferrule, which would be removed for the OPs purpose.

Comment: What is the rubber thing within the FIP?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Here is the part I used:  WATTS LFA-124.  Found it at Home Depot in the aisle with brass fittings.