# How can I connect or union two flexible water supply lines with female connectors of diameters 1/2" and 3/8"?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, connectors

I was replacing my kitchen faucet when I ran into an issue that I didn't foresee (yes, this is my fault for not looking ahead!). The supply lines attached to the faucet and the supply lines coming from the angle stop do not connect together (two female ends) and are of different sizes. The water supply lines have 1/2 inch female connectors and the lines coming from the faucet have 3/8 inch female connectors. What's more, the supply lines from the angle stop are crimped to the stop and can't be easily removed.

**1/2 inch female flexible supply line coming from angle stop**
[image: 1/2 inch female flexible supply line]

**3/8 inch female flexible supply line coming from faucet**
[image: 3/8 inch female flexible supply line]

**angle stop with crimped supply line (the other end is the 1/2 inch female hex connector)**
[image: angle stop with crimped supply line]

Now, what I would like to do is connect these supply tubes to each other because there is not an easy way for me to replace the stops, uncrimp the water supply lines, or remove or replace the faucet supply lines.

I believe my question is similar to this one.

[Connect 1/2" supply line to 3/8" outer diameter faucet line](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68742/connect-1-2-supply-line-to-3-8-outer-diameter-faucet-line)

Unfortunately, I am unsure of the appropriate diameters to consider when purchasing something because I do not know if the connectors on my lines are NPT (taper) threaded or compression (parallel) threaded.

I have seen there are adapters like compression unions and reducing nipples, but I am unsure of which kind to buy or if there are any for my situation. Another idea I had was to join the two lines using another angle stop, such as the one below, but I am also unsure if that would work or even be a sound solution.

[1/2 in. Nominal Compression Inlet x 3/8 in. O.D. Compression Outlet Multi-Turn Angle Valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Nominal-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-O-D-Compression-Outlet-Multi-Turn-Angle-Valve-OCR19X-C1/202047058#product-overview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Get 3/8" male to 1/2" male nipple.

Note you need two wrenches and one of these:

[image]

One wrench on the hex nipple, one wrench on the hex female nut, and the pliers above to hold the crimped part of the flexible pipe to prevent it from turning. If the flexible pipe turns, it'll either unscrew from below the socket and you'll get a leak, or it'll bend at awkward angles which will damage the stainless steel weave (that might cause it to burst after a few years) or crush the internal rubber pipe so you get less water flow.

Comment: I agree with you that there shouldn't be any attempt to turn the crimped part, but I'm not sure that it really needs to be held. Turn the nipple into the supply line until it's finger tight, then one wrench on the free brass nut on the supply line and another on the nipple - hold the nipple still, turn the nut. The nut should spin freely on the supply line. Besides, where's that third hand going to come from?

Comment: When you turn the nut, the flexible pipe usually wants to turn along with it. It's doable with 2 hands.

Comment: 3/8 pipe thread is uncommon in sink plumbing -- IMHO the 3/8 size is most likely to be compression thread while the 1/2 is pipe thread. The adapter pictured looks as if it might be pipe thread on both sides.

Comment: The hex connectors are the kind that spin independently of the hose they are connected too, as @FreeMan says. Do I still need the wrenches and pliers?

Comment: @Dorik you'll need wrenches to tighten the spinning nuts onto the nipple you pick up. I agree that you'll want to be careful to _not_ twist the flex lines, but I don't think you'll need the 3rd wrench. I've tightened these flex lines onto faucets and toilets and not had issues with them binding/twisting at the other end. bobflux does think you'll need it a 3rd wrench to prevent that from happening. I think the best thing is for you to be careful as you tighten and _be prepared_ for the line to start twisting and STOP if it does and reassess your procedure from there.

Comment: @FreeMan Okay. I'm going to hunt down one of these adapters and give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe they put some lube on the American ones so the flex line doesn't spin, that would actually be a good idea lol.

Comment: Don't fit any of this without using ptfe tape. Since they're not tapered, they will screw to the end, and will potentially leak. Ptfe will make the joint watertight. I sometimes end up using a washer to screw down onto as well.

Comment: Alright, it worked! Here is the part I ended up using.

[3/8 in. Compression x 1/2 in. MIP Brass Adapter Fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-8-in-Compression-x-1-2-in-MIP-Brass-Adapter-Fitting-2-Pack-800769/207176557#overlay)

I screwed the adapter into the 1/2 inch fitting by hand. To tighten it, I used 1 pair of pliers to hold the fitting so it wouldn't spin, and another pair to turn the adapter into the fitting. Then I just screwed the 3/8 inch fitting onto the other end like normal and tightened it with pliers.

Comment: @Tim is correct and I figured this out the hard way when  I opened the valves and the adapter connection started leaking :).  I wrapped the threads of the adapter in PTFE tape and that stopped the leaks.

Comment: @Dorik - great! Pity I didn't post an answer before you started work..!

Comment: lol home depot doesn't like the French, I get 403 Forbidden on that link. Is it the same as [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/114782957318)?

Comment: @Tim Both of the hoses have a rubber washer visible inside them. They also have swivel nuts. Both of these are signs that _threads aren't the sealing surface_ (with a compression type fitting, the thread is _never_ the sealing surface). Therefore PTFE tape or pipe dope are unnecessary. If a compression or washer/gasket/o-ring sealed joint leaks it's either not tightened properly or is physically damaged and should be replaced.

Comment: @GregHill Yeah I'm quite intrigued by the idea of PTFE tape on a free rotating nut, especially because it worked, because it shouldn't work at all. I think OP didn't get the nipple with the flat ends that normally fits flat against the rubber washer and compresses it as it should, but another type of nipple instead that's not designed for rubber washers, maybe it has slanted or conical ends, that would cut into the rubber washer.

Comment: @bobflux Good ideas about the shape of the nipple. The PTFE may have "worked" in that it provided lubrication, making it easier to tighten the nut sufficiently so the washer could effect a seal. Also the disassembly provided a chance that the parts could be rotated so they engage differently; simply "take it apart and try again" might have made the difference.

Comment: @GregHill Is also right. When I applied the PTFE tape, I noticed that the threads did not bind as much, allowing me to tighten the nut a bit further, so that might be the real reason. The clue about the nut having a rubber washer inside of it, along with adapter with flat ends, are things I'll have to keep in mind for the future. Although hopefully I won't have this same kind of issue again. bobflux Yes, the link you posted is the same product as the one I used.

Comment: Does it really matter? Ptfe works, there's no denying that. Use it or not - so what? Belt and braces, and a piece of string. If it does the job, so what?

Comment: @Tim Nothing wrong with belt and braces to secure the trousers, but if one's neck tie is drooping into the lunch plate those are no help. A tie tack is needed. People sometimes use both dope and PTFE tape on stubborn tapered pipe thread joints. But when the seal depends on a rubber gasket or metal-to-metal face contact as in these hoses, compression fittings, unions, or BSPP thread, PTFE tape on the true sealing surface is debris and can prevent proper sealing. The point is to understand the joint and which sealing aids are applicable to it - there are plenty where PTFE has no place.

Comment: OK so the fitting has [sharp ends](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/keAAAOSw-I9gh2pr/s-l500.jpg) that aren't designed to mate with the a rubber seal in the flex line, so it leaked.